# Usage of 'could' and 'would'

Tags: grammar

I'm not a native English speaker, and the use of could and would always confuses me. Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: @edwin it isnt helpul.

Comment: Here's another previous question: _What is this “should?”_ And if you look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+is+this+should) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=modal+would), you should find links to many previous discussions.

Comment: Have a look at previous posts on this site (use search, as well). See also: [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

*Could* refers to possibility (or its lack), and *would* to action (or its lack).

> I wish I could fly.

I can't fly; it's not a thing I am capable of doing.

> If I were a bird, I could fly.

Birds of course can fly (most species, anyway) so if I was a bird I would be capable of doing so.

> If I were a bird, I would fly.

Not only would I be capable of it, in this scenario it is actually going to happen.

In this way, *could* is related to *can* and *would* is related to *will*.

You have them together in:

> If I could, I would.